# Why does this equal True and thus render a div in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic, jsx

I'm a little confused why this will render when `errors.email` is not a falsey value. Does the JSX get ignored and it only looks at errors.email on the right-hand side so basically the expression is `if (errors.email && errors.email)` ?

Just a little strange. I've never seen this before.

```
{ errors.email && ( <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.email}</div> ) }
```

Comment: The JSX expression becomes a string, and a non-empty string, so that's the value of the overall expression.

Comment: oh so the right-hand side, because it's a non-empty string, will always be true. then once there's errors.email, the whole expression becomes true?

Comment: Well yes, but understand that `&&` and `||` are not like Java or C++; they do not necessarily yield a boolean result. They *check* the subexpressions for "truthiness", but the yielded value is the un-converted value of the left side (if it's "falsy") or the right side.

Comment: @Pointy: Not a string, the object created by `React.createElement`. (Thanks for pointing out my mistake earlier, btw. Need more coffee.)

Comment: Ah I think I understand. Thanks for your help, guys

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah OK, well whatever it is, it'll be something and not nothing and therefore truthy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike some other languages, `&&` and `||` do not necessarily result in `true` or `false`; instead, they take the value of one of their operands.

In the case of `&&`:

- If `errors.email` is *falsy*, the result of the `&&` expression is the value of `errors.email` (and the right-hand side is never evaluated).
- If `errors.email` is *truthy*, then the right-hand side is evaluated and (a reference to) the object created by it becomes the result of the `&&` expression.